# Relating enums and using in generics

Tags: java, generics, enums

I need to create enums for countries and states.

1. What's the most appropriate way to create and relate these enums (as in country X can have states P, Q, R and so on)?
2. If I have a generic class parameterized with a Country type, can I declare a method which will accept a State only available to the specific country?

For example something like:

```
public abstract class TestClass <T extends Country> {
    public void addState(T.State state);
    public List<T.State> getSelectedStates();
}
```

**Edit 1:** For easier maintenance, I would prefer to have a separate State enum for each Country as opposed to a single State enum with hundreds of states of all countries. Please comment.

**Edit 2:** I used the following solution for a problem very similar to this.

**Solution:** As @Bohemian suggested,

```
interface Country { }
interface State<T extends Country> { }

public class Countries {
    public static class USA implements Country { }
    public static class India implements Country { }
}

enum UsaStateEnum implements State<Countries.USA> {
    NY, MA, MD, CA
}

enum IndiaStateEnum implements State<Countries.India> {
    DEL, BLR
}

class GenericClass<T extends Country> {

    List<State<T>> states;

    public void addState(State<T> state) {
        if (states == null) {
            states = new ArrayList<State<T>>();
        }
        states.add(state);
    }

    public List<State<T>> getSelectedStates() {
        return states;
    }
}

public class NestedEnumTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericClass<Countries.USA> obj = new GenericClass<Countries.USA>();
        obj.addState(UsaStateEnum.MA);
        // obj.addState(IndiaStateEnum.DEL); // NOT ALLOWED

        List<State<Countries.USA>> states = obj.getSelectedStates();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer part 1, you can define two enums, one of which references the other, like this:

```
public enum State {
    A, B, C, D, E
}

public enum Country {
    USA(State.A, State.B),
    UK(State.C, State.D);

    private final List<State> states;

    Country(State... states) {
        this.states = Arrays.asList(states);
    }

    public List<State> getStates() {
        return states;
    }
}
```

To answer part 2, "no" - there is no way to restrict instances of a particular class to a subset.

You could if you defined a separate class for each country and a separate enum for the states it has, but this doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: Thanks much. Could you please verify below if my understanding of your last statement ("You could if you defined a separate class for each...") is correct?

    enum CountryEnum implements Country { USA, INDIA }  

    enum UsaStateEnum implements State { NY, MA }  

    enum IndiaStateEnum implements State { DEL, BLR }  

    abstract class TestClass <T extends Country, U extends State> {  
        public void addState(U state);  
      public List<U> getSelectedStates();  
    }

Comment: As I think more about it, I'd actually prefer to have a separate State enum for each Country as opposed to a single State enum with hundreds of states of all countries.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an enum implement an interface like this:

```
public enum MyEnum implements MyInterface<MyType> {
    // ...
}
```

Apart from implementing interfaces `enum`s do not support inheritance yet but if you wish to have common functionality in your `enum`s you can always compose for example some **strategy** object into them.

Comment: Not sure if this helps here, though. (Not sure I understand the question, either).

Comment: Yeah, it is somewhat vague and obscure to me too.

Comment: "yet?" Are there plans? (Especially seeing that they already extend java.lang.Enum).

Comment: I don't know about them but I never thought java will have closures and here we are :)

Comment: @Thilo, AdamArold: Please let me know the part in my question which is not clear so that I can elaborate. Thanks!